# Getting absolute path in boost

Tags: boost

I have a file in my home directory:

```
~/abc.csv
```

I want to get the complete absolute path which would be:

```
/home/nishant/abs.csv
```

How do I get it?

I thought canonical would help, but for canonical to work, the file should `exists`, and the `exists` function on `~/abc.csv` returns false.

Answer (score 2):

This is not making the path absolute, nor making it canonical.

It's shell expansion of the `~` character. And it's not a feature in Boost Filesystem, as such.

You can code it yourself:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f1714e33a25d741)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::filesystem::path;

path expand(path p) {
    char const* const home = getenv("HOME");
    if (home == nullptr)
        return p; // TODO handle as error?

    auto s = p.generic_string<std::string>();
    if (!s.empty() && s.find("~/") == 0u) {
        return home + s.substr(1);
    }
    return p;
}


int main() {
    path sample = "~/test.cpp";
    std::cout << expand(sample) << "\n";
}
```

Which, on my system prints "/home/sehe/test.cpp"

Comment: thanks very much....I thought the expansion would be handled by Boost in case of linux OS